# c - accessing value.type when iterating bson

Tags: c, mongodb, struct, bson, mongo-c-driver

I am trying to follow the libbson API documentation. But it seems I got something wrong. The [documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/libbson/1.0.0/bson_value_t.html) states you can do:

```
const bson_value_t *value;

value = bson_iter_value (&iter);

if (value.type == BSON_TYPE_INT32) {
   printf ("%d\n", value.value.v_int32);
}
```

But when I try compile actual code with it I get the following error:

```
example1.c:34:64: error: request for member ‘type’ in something not a structure or union
```

And here is the actual code:

```
#include <bson.h>
#include <mongoc.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int
main (int   argc,
              char *argv[])
{
    mongoc_client_t *client;
    mongoc_collection_t *collection;
    mongoc_cursor_t *cursor;
    const bson_t *doc;
    const bson_value_t *value;
    bson_t *query;
    char *str;
    bson_iter_t iter;
    bson_type_t type;
    mongoc_init ();

    client = mongoc_client_new ("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
    collection = mongoc_client_get_collection (client, "test", "test");
    query = bson_new ();
    cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, query, NULL, NULL);

    while (mongoc_cursor_next (cursor, &doc)) {
            str = bson_as_json (doc, NULL);
            if (bson_iter_init (&iter, doc)) {
               while (bson_iter_next (&iter)) {
                     printf ("Found element key: \"%s\"\n", bson_iter_key (&iter));
                        type = bson_iter_type (&iter);
                        printf("type %d\n", (int)type);
                        value = bson_iter_value (&iter);
                        printf("Found values of type %d", value.type);
                     }
            }
            bson_free(str);
        }

    bson_destroy (query);
    mongoc_cursor_destroy (cursor);
    mongoc_collection_destroy (collection);
    mongoc_client_destroy (client);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The documentation has a typo, it should be `value->type`.

Comment: @immibis are you sure? When I tried this I got: ` example1.c|34 col 64 error| ‘bson_value_t’ has no member named ‘type’ `

Comment: ... it should be `value->value_type`. File a bug report or something, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value` is a pointer. You need to de-reference it:

```
value->type
```

or

```
(*value).type
```

Besides that, according to [the documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/libbson/1.0.0/bson_value_t.html), `bson_value_t` has no member called `type`. Perhaps they mean

```
value->value_type
```

Comment: When I tried this I got: ` example1.c|34 col 64 error| ‘bson_value_t’ has no member named ‘type’

Comment: @Oz123 Fine, then the documentation is wrong. But this fixes the error in the code you posted.

Comment: yes the documentation is wrong ! it should be `(*value).value_type);`